# why i can't read txt file to double scale number by using stream in c++

Tags: c++, c++14

i wonder why i can't read .txt file....
i wana change double scale number in .txt file to vector
and my .txt file is

0.03 0.0157073 -3.6957e-08

0.055 0.0314108 2.40555e-06

2 line samples

i want to read this data to double numbers.....

```
    #include "CurveFitting.h"
    #include <cmath>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>        
    
    void CurveFitting::txtCurveFitting() {
        std::ifstream file(filename);
        if(!file){
            std::cout<<"fail to read file"<<std::endl;
        }
        auto **myArray= new double *[term];
        for(int i=0; i<term; ++i){
            myArray[i]=new double [4];
        }
    
        auto *datax = new float[numOfData];
        auto *datay = new float[numOfData];
        auto *dataz = new float[numOfData];
    
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfData; i++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < term; k++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                    file >> myArray[k][j];
                }
            }
            time = myArray[term][0];
            frequency = myArray[term][1];
            output = myArray[term][3];
    
            saveCurveFitting();
    
            datax[i] = (float) cos((2 * pi) * frequency * time);
            datay[i] = (float) sin((2 * pi) * frequency * time);
            dataz[i] = (float) output;
        }
        file.close();
    
        for(int i=0; i<term; ++i){
            delete[] myArray[i];
        }delete[] myArray;
    
        delete[] datax;
        delete[] datay;
        delete[] dataz;
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but if the code can't open the file, it should probably return immediately rather than creating a bunch of garbage data. Also, you don't need to call `file.close();`; the destructor will do that. And, finally, don't do all those `new`s and `delete`s. Use `std::vector`; it will save you many headaches.

Comment: `time = myArray[term][0];` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. Valid indexes into `myArray` are `0` through `term-1`

Comment: I'd start with something like: `struct point { double x, y, z; }; std::vector<point> points;`

Comment: It seems, like your source file has only 3 values per row, but you are trying to read 4 values in the input loop. But there is not enough information. VTC